# Can I change visibility of button (<div class="btn export-btn") in outer div style class?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a code:

```
<div class="mycontainer1" style="....">
   <table class="widget title list" id="element-545">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td class="txt">11111</td>
         <td class="toolbar" id="element-546">
           <div class="btn export-btn" id="element-549">
             <span class="fa fa-print"></span>Export
           </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

I need set style for class `"btn export-btn"` `visibility: hidden` in css.

Can I resolve it in class of first div (mycontainer1)?
Touch only the first div!

Comment: `.mycontainer1 .btn-export { visibility: hidden}`

Comment: Thanks, guys, but can I resolve it use only .mycontainer { ... } ?

Comment: No, just because you would set the `mycontainer1` invisible too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

.mycontainer1 .btn.export-btn {

Comment: .mycontainer1 .btn.export-btn {
   visibility: hidden;
}

Accidentaly pressed enter

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .mycontainer1 .btn.export-btn
 {
    visibility: hidden;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Context, please